# OpenCV3.4.2 : Can not read file both imread and cvLoadImage

Tags: c++, opencv

I wrote a little demo to test whether my OpenCV work or not.
My computer contains version **3.4.2** and **3.4.0**.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("map.jpg");
    cv::imshow("test", image);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

CMake file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(opencv_test VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package( OpenCV 3.4.2 REQUIRED )
add_executable(opencv_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(opencv_test ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Then it throw the exception like this:

```sh
 OpenCV(3.4.2) /home/robomaster/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

**I have tried and checked the following  methods:**

1. check the *absolute* and *relative* path and they are correct.
2. check `imread()` and `cvLoadImage()` and the ouptut is the same.

#### And I have no idea how to fix it. Any help will be grateful!!

Comment: The image should be in the same folder as your cpp file.

Comment: I‘ve checked it and they are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

As per OpenCV [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56),

> If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper
> permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an
> empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL )

which means that after `cv::imread` you should check:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("map.jpg");
if( image.data == nullptr )
  return 1; // EXIT_ERROR
```

Again, as per the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56), possible reasons for failure are:

- missing file
- improper permissions
- unsupported or invalid format

Possible solutions:

- Use full path, check file existence
- `chmod +w map.jpg`
- Change image format